# Git commit manually editting hunk

Tags: git, git-commit

So I have a problem adding hunks for my commit properly.

I have something like so:

```
@@ -6,6 +9,5 @@
#include "incfile.h"

 bool func3(int&, const char*);
-int func1(const int, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<type> >&);
-void func2(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<type> >&);
+int func1(const int, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<type> >&);
 void func4(const int);
```

I am trying to only stage only the change to `func2` I want t he changes to `func1` in a diff commit, and I am struggling because every time and every combination of me removing `-` or lines or whatever is resulting in a patch that doesn't apply. I thought that I could simply remove the `-` from in front of `func1` and delete the `+` line for `func1` and it would be fine but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
 int func1(const int, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<type> >&);
-void func2(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<type> >&);
```

In other words, replace the first `-` with a  (space) and completely delete the last line.

Comment: I have tried that and it still says the patch doesn't apply

Comment: Please give the exact error. Also what command do you execute to stage the file?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to stage the file?

Comment: I'm doing a `git add -p file` and I have 3 chunks the first one I am not adding this is the second and the third I am not adding.

Comment: And you press 'e' at the second chunk? Also, is the third chunk relevant to the second?

Comment: I press e on the second chunk yes and no the third is separate and has no relation to the second

Comment: Can you try pressing 's' when the second chunk appears and apply each line as you want?

Comment: It will not split it into individual lines. I however fixed it I had to edit the file as a whole and do as you said and it worked fine but for some reason because I was doing it in the split it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could try `git rebase -i ...` to set up a range of commits for mangling. One of the options the `-i` (interactive) flag gives on each commit is to `e`dit it. That makes the process stop, so you can change the commit at leisure (in this case, editing the modified file to taste), then `git add incfile.h` to record the change, and `git rebase --continue` to replay the other commits.

If you are paranoid, you could create a branch off the tip to fool around and don't risk losing it by `git checkout -b experiment` and work on the new `experiment` branch.