# Manually editing a git add --patch results in error (patch failed)

Tags: git

I have this hunk, and I'd like to edit it so that the changes to `uuid` are ignored.

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide.
@@ -43,4 +44,7 @@
        "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
-       "uuid": "^8.3.2"
+       "imask": "^6.1.0",
+       "uuid": "^8.3.2",
+       "validator": "^13.6.0",
+       "vest": "^3.2.5"
    }
 }
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
```

My idea so far is to do the following which would mean the hunk header doesn't need to change (right?).

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide.
@@ -43,4 +44,7 @@
        "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2"
+       "imask": "^6.1.0",
+       "validator": "^13.6.0",
+       "vest": "^3.2.5"
    }
 }
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
```

But still, after saving changes and quitting I get the following:

```sh
error: patch failed: package.json:43
error: package.json: patch does not apply
```

At this point, I'm confused and I'm not sure what to try. At first I thought it was the missing space because my VIM configuration replaces it with tabs, but manually adding the space doesn't fix it either (in the `-` line).

My only guess so far is that it's a problem with the header, but it should line up correctly right? I'm still adding `7` lines in both cases and the `4` stays the same.

I've reviewed [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824647/manually-editing-using-git-add-patch-filename) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078931/git-commit-manually-editting-hunk) but haven't found something tackling such problem.

I could try and use a GUI, but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Any ideas? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: "because my VIM configuration replaces it with tabs" probably deserves more investigation. I think silently changing white space is a bad default setting for a vimrc.

Comment: @jthill sorry, it's the other way around, it changes tabs to spaces

Comment: but yeah, I'll investigate more and see if there's anything there

Comment: What got me to comment was, I was looking at the patch edits thinking "there's nothing wrong there, why is this failing" and arrived at whitespace trouble before reading the end of your question. But I haven't done a whole lot of hunk editing so this is just me tossing my two bits in.

Comment: Note that there's never[1] any need to adjust the hunk headers here: the patch code uses `--recount` to get Git to ignore the header counts in the first place. But yes, the change you show *should* apply, so tabs-vs-spaces seems a likely culprit. [1: modulo bugs in the source code of course; but a bug around re-count is unlikely. Some versions of Git have a bug with add --patch whose details I have forgotten but it's not related to line counts.]

Comment: FWIW : note that applying the patch you present in your question would lead to an invalid `package.json` file : there wouldn't be a `,` (a coma) after the `"uuid": "^8.3.2"` entry

Comment: Another user stumbled on a similar issue using `git add -p` : [Can't remove line from being added to staging area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62896307/cant-remove-line-from-being-added-to-staging-area/62897311#62897311) Did you have to `[s]plit` a hunk before choosing to edit that hunk around `"uuid"` ?

Comment: @LeGEC yes! I did had to split it first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you fell on the same issue as [this other user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62896307/cant-remove-line-from-being-added-to-staging-area/62897311#62897311) : if you split a hunk in `git add -p`, there is a bug that prevents applying "edit manually" a sub hunk.

The workaround is simple : put aside your current version of `package.json`, and edit that file to the version you want to commit.

Also worth noting : `git gui` offers a perfectly functional "stage this line" action -- when you right click on any line in the diff displayed in the right pane.

Comment: The workaround works simple enough! Thanks!

Comment: Tried using `git gui` but I'm getting some obscure error with very few results on Google. `error: git-gui died of signal 11`. I'm unable to use it so far, in Arch Linux (Manjaro).